# HOW to setup remote_listener in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two oracle database servers **DB1** and **DB2**.
In both servers i have a user **USER1**.
What ever the request coming in to DB2 i want to redirect to **DB1** .
Anybody can help please?

Comment: I don't know. But, what do you need the DB2 for if everything that regards that database should be redirected to DB1? Shut DB2 down and work only with DB1.

Comment: Yes.. I will take the full dump of USER1 of DB2 database and import in USER1 of DB1.  Finally will shutdown the DB2 database but listener will listen to incoming requests  and forward to DB1. That is the plan. But i want to preserve the IP and port for the users of this database.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a database(DB1 or DB2)  for connecting a client using a special service name. You can dynamically redefine the service name by running the command on DB1

```
alter system set service_names='app_service_primary' scope=memory;
```

redirect to DB2

1) DB1

```
 alter system set service_names='app_service_db1' scope=memory;
```

2) DB2

```
alter system set service_names='app_service_primary' scope=memory;

app_service=
(DESCRIPTION =
    (FAILOVER=ON) 
    (LOAD_BALANCE=off)  
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.xx.yyy.88)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.xx.yyy.89)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = app_service_primary)
      (FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=select)(METHOD=basic))
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )
```